# Selenium webDriver: Selecting span class in a class

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

i am new to selenium webdriver. I have a problem trying to select an item in a span class from the following

```
<a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a>
```

I have tried using this to  no avail

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@class='ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all']//span[@class='ui-icon ui-icon-closethick']"
```

Could anyone please advise what is wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in the xpath.

Either `tag name` or `*` is needed before specifying the attribute using `[]`.

e.g. `//a[@class='foo']` means search for all matching tags called "a" which have a class attribute called "foo"

or use //*[@class='foo'] which means search for all tags with `any` name, wich have a class attribute called "foo".

so your xpath should look like

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all']//span[@class='ui-icon ui-icon-closethick']"))
```

So "a" was missing at the start of your xpath.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score -1):

XPath should be like,

```
XPath = //SPAN[@class='ui-icon ui-icon-closethick']
```

Or

```
XPath= //A[@class='ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all']//span[@class='ui-icon ui-icon-closethick']
```